# Как выбрать значения столбцов по колонке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица с книгами:

| Author | book_id | q-ty_read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AuthorA | 3915 | 5 |
| AuthorA | 7867 | 7 |
| AuthorB | 3756 | 17 |
| AuthorC | 8768 | 19 |
| AuthorC | 3112 | 27 |
| AuthorC | 523 | 101 |
| AuthorD | 54332 | 22 |
| AuthorD | 543 | 2 |

Задача - найти самую популярную книгу у автора по количеству прочитываний (q-ty_read).

Итог должен быть примерно в таком виде:

```
AuthorA|7867|7  
AuthorB|3756|17  
AuthorC|523|101  
AuthorD|54332|22
```

Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно есть что-то поизящнее, но мне ночью в голову ничего лучше такого варианта не приходит:

```
res= df.groupby("Author", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by="q-ty_read", ascending=False).iloc[0])
```

res:

```
    Author  book_id  q-ty_read
0  AuthorA     7867          7
1  AuthorB     3756         17
2  AuthorC      523        101
3  AuthorD    54332         22
```

*UPDATE*

Вариант 2, без группировки вообще:

```
res = df.sort_values(["Author", "q-ty_read"], ascending=[True,False]).drop_duplicates(subset="Author", keep="first")
```

res, соответственно, так же:

```
    Author  book_id  q-ty_read
1  AuthorA     7867          7
2  AuthorB     3756         17
5  AuthorC      523        101
6  AuthorD    54332         22
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) и [DataFrame.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
res = (df
       .groupby("Author", group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, "q-ty_read")))
```

результат:

```
In [7]: res
Out[7]:
    Author  book_id  q-ty_read
1  AuthorA     7867          7
2  AuthorB     3756         17
5  AuthorC      523        101
6  AuthorD    54332         22
```